# Sorting an Object Array by it's Title. Flash - Actionscript 2

Tags: arrays, flash, sorting, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have an array of objects. My object has it's title inside of it as a reference. I need to sort my array of objects in Alphabetical order by title.

Below is what I've been playing with, trying to accomplish this goal.
As an example, i stored the title reference on my array objects as index 0. On index 1 i stored an ID reference just to check against the result of my sorted array.

The last output I'm getting from flash, is ordered in such a weird way that makes absolutely no sense to me. Please help! I'm open to different methods of accomplishing the same goal.

```
//This is an example list of my objects, and their test titles.

var obj = Array("ants", 24);
var obj2 = Array("cants", 29);
var obj3 = Array("xants", 35);
var obj4 = Array("bants", 80);

//Hear I assign each object to an array
var test = Array(obj, obj2, obj3, obj4);

//I create 2 arrays. 1 to store the titles in, and 1 for the object itself.
var alpha_sort = Array();
var obj_index = Array();

for(var i in test){//loop through all properties
    alpha_sort.push(test[i][0]);
    obj_index.push(test[i]);
}

trace('----- Display unsorted list ------');

for(var i in alpha_sort){//loop through all properties
    trace(i+' - '+alpha_sort[i]);
}

trace('----- Display sorted list ------');

alpha_sort.sort(2);
for(var i in alpha_sort){//loop through all properties
    trace(i+' - '+alpha_sort[i]+ ' - '+obj_index[i][1]);
}
```

The Output is:

```
----- Display unsorted list ------
3 - ants
2 - cants
1 - xants
0 - bants
----- Display sorted list ------
2 - bants - 29
1 - cants - 35
0 - xants - 80
3 - ants - 24
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by either converting your array values to objects (instead of sub arrays) and using the `sortOn` method,  or creating a custom sort function.

I'd reccomend to prior:   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000751.html

```
var test = Array({title: "ants", value: 24}, {title: "cants", value: 29},{title: "xants", value: 35});

test.sortOn("title");
```

To use a custom sort function:

```
test.sort(sortTitle);

function sortTitle(a, b):Number {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) {
    return -1;
    } else if (a[0]>a[0]) {
    return 1;
    } else {
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The sortOn that you mentioned above is actually exactly what I've been trying to use now, however it's having very odd behavior. It doesn't seem to want to work for numerics, even using key 8 in the function..  What im doing realistically here, is trying to actually sort movie clip depths, by their titles.  So it is indeed an object setup exactly like you mentioned above, and not like my array example.

Comment: for numerical sorting, use `Array.NUMERIC` or `16`, not 8.  Show your real code so everyone knows what you're actually trying to do. What is the purpose of your number in the object?